# how do I keep my function from fill in address multiple times?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am using google places api to fill in address data, I have possibly up to 11 addresses that might be entered, the problem is for each address it is filling the data in automatically for all 5 forms.I only want it to fill in the address for the slideid it is on. I want to do this without making x amount of copies of my function, but I am stuck on how to go about it. 
here is some code to show what I am doing. First I call init code for autocomplete. whichSlide is initialized in global to be equal to zero as we count from 0

```
function initAutoCompleteDynamic() {

//I could have used a loop here for simplicity sake I am just doing manaully for now. 
//set property values here.. .

    autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('prop1address0')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });

    autocomplete1.addListener('place_changed', fillinAddressDynamic);

    autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('prop1address1')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });

    autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', fillinAddressDynamic);
    }

   //here I call fillinAddressDynamic 


function fillinAddressDynamic() {

    alert("value of which slide is " + whichSlide);

    var place = autocomplete1.getPlace();
    var success = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        var field = addressType;
        var completeaddress = '';
        if (componentFormProduction[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentFormProduction[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(cR0[addressType]).value = val;

            if (field == "street_number") {
                var streetnum = document.getElementById("streetnumber0").value = val;

            }
            if (field == "route") {
                if (streetnum) {
                    completeaddress1 = streetnum + ' ' + val;
                }
                else {
                    completeaddress1 = val;
                }
                document.getElementById('prop1address0').value = completeaddress1;
            }
        }

    }
    whichSlide++;


        var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        var field = addressType;
        var completeaddress = '';
        if (componentFormProduction[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentFormProduction[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(cR1[addressType]).value = val;

            if (field == "street_number") {
                var streetnum = document.getElementById("streetnumber1").value = val;

            }
            if (field == "route") {
                if (streetnum) {
                    completeaddress1 = streetnum + ' ' + val;
                }
                else {
                    completeaddress1 = val;
                }
                document.getElementById('prop1address1').value = completeaddress1;
            }
        }

    }
    whichSlide++;
```

}

Since it was asked for here is the base form which is being recreated via the function below.

```
        function GetPropertySlide(idx, slideID) {
    var retval = "" +
        "<div id = 'hidden" + slideID + "' class='item lx-width-690 lx-align-center OtherIncomeSlidePropertyAddresses'>" +
        "<div id = 'slideNumber" + idx + "'class='item lx-width-690 lx-align-center'>" +
        "   <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].ID' id='propertyID" + idx + "' type='hidden' value='0'>" +

        "   <div class='lx-row lx-font-bold lx-font-size-26 lx-margin-top-30'>" +
        "       Tell us about property # " + (idx + 1) + "  - Dynamic properties slide" + "?" +
        "   </div>" +
        "   <div class='lx-row'>" +
        "       <button type='button' style = 'button margin-left:10px;' class='btn-btn-success' onclick='InitiateDeleteProperty(" + idx + ");'>Delete Me!</button>" +
        "       <button type='button' style = 'button margin-left:10px;' class='btn-btn-danger' onclick='clearform();'>Clear Me!</button>" +
        "       <button type='button' style = 'button margin-left:10px;' class='btn-btn-danger margin left 10px'  onclick='MarketValue();'>Pull Market Value</button>" +
        "       <button type='button' style = 'button margin-left:10px;' class='btn-btn-danger margin left 10px'  onclick='initAutoCompleteDynamic()'>Pull Address</button>" +
        "   </div>" +
        "   <div id='divpropaddress" + idx + "' class='lx-width-100-pct lx-align-center lx-row'>" +
        "   <div class='lx-row lx-width-550'>" +
        "     <div class='lx-word-wrap lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-top-30'>" +
        "         Address" +
        "     </div>" +
        "     <div class='lx-width-100-pct lx-margin-top-8'>" +
        "         <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].Address' class='form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id = 'prop1address" + idx + "'  type='text' value='' autocomplete='off' />" +
        "         </div>" +
        "   </div> " +
        "   <div class='lx-row lx-margin-top-15'>" +
        "   <input id= 'streetnumber" + idx + "'type='text'>' " +
        "   </div>" +
        "   <div class='lx-row lx-margin-top-15'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-margin-right-15'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-font-size-18'> " +
        "              City" +
        "          </div> " +
        "          <div class='lx-width-250  lx-margin-top-8'>" +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].City' class='form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id = 'prop1city" + idx + "'  type='text' value='' autocomplete='off' />" +
        "          </div>" +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left  lx-margin-right-15'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-font-size-18'> " +
        "              State" +
        "          </div> " +
        "          <div class='lx-width-150 lx-margin-top-8'> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].State' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id = 'prop1state" + idx + "' type='text' value='' autocomplete = 'off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-font-size-18'> " +
        "              Zip Code" +
        "          </div> " +
        "          <div class='lx-width-120 lx-margin-top-8'> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].ZipCode' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id = 'prop1zipcode" + idx + "' autocomplete = 'off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div class='lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-top-15'> What type of Property do you Own?</div> " +
        "   <div class='lx-float-left'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-15'> " +
        "          <select class='lx-form-properties-control lx-color-1 lx-height-42 ' + data-val='true' + data-val-number='The field PropertyTypeID must be a number.' + data-val-required='The PropertyTypeID field is required.' id = 'propertytypeid" + idx + "' name='Properties[" + idx + "].PropertyTypeID'><option value='- 1'>Property Type</option>' " +
        "              <option value= '0' > Single Family</option >" +
        "              <option value='1'>Condos/Co-op</option>" +
        "              <option value='2'>Townhouse</option>" +
        "              <option value='3'>Multi Family</option>" +
        "              <option value='4'>Manufactured</option>" +
        "          </select >" +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +
        "   <div class='lx-margin-top-60 lx-row '> " +
        "      <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left lx-margin-top-30'> " +
        "          <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].HasRental' class='form-control lx-font-color-lightblack' id='HasRental" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val-required='The HasRental field is required.' data-val='' /> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-36 lx-width-75-pct'> " +
        "          I am renting this property." +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id= 'divmonthlyrentrow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-8 hidden'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-8'> " +
        "              What is the monthly rent you are collecting? " +
        "          </div> " +
        "       </div> " +
        "       <div class='lx-row '> " +
        "          <div class='input-icon'> " +
        "              <i> $</i> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].monthlyrent' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id = 'monthlyrent" + idx + "' autocomplete = 'off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divtaxrow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row'> " +
        "       <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left'> " +
        "          <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].IsTaxIncluded' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack' id = 'IsTaxIncluded" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val=''/>" +
        "       </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-10 lx-width-75-pct'> " +
        "          Tax included in payment ? " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divtaxamountrow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-15  hidden'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-word-wrap lx-font-size-18 '> " +
        "              Tax Amount" +
        "              <button type= 'button' style = 'button margin-left:10px;' class='btn-btn-primary margin left 5px '  onclick= 'PullAmount();' title='Pull Tax Amount'>Pull</button > " +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='input-icon'> " +
        "              <i> $</i> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].TaxAmount' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42 lx-margin-top-15' id = 'taxamount" + idx + "' type='text' value='' data-val-required='The TaxAmount field is required.' data-val='true' data-val-number='The field TaxAmount must be a number.' autocomplete='off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divinsurancerow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left'> " +
        "          <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].IsInsuranceIncluded' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack' id = 'IsInsuranceIncluded" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val=''/>" +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-10'> " +
        "          Insurance included in payment ? " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divfloodinsurancerow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row hidden'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-word-wrap lx-font-size-18'> " +
        "              Homeowner / Flood Insurance Amount" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='input-icon'> " +
        "              <i> $</i> " +
        "              <input name=Properties[" + idx + "].InsuranceAmount' class='form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42' id ='InsuranceAmount" + idx + "' type='text' value='' data-val-number='The field InsuranceAmount must be a number.' autocomplete='off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'hoafee" + idx + "' class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row'>" +
        "      <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left'> " +
        "          <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].IsHOA' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack', id = 'IsHOA" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val=''/>" +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-10 '> " +
        "          Do you have a Homeowners Association? " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divassociationfeerow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row hidden'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-bottom-6'> " +
        "              Homeowner Association / Condo Fees" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='input-icon'> " +
        "              <i> $</i> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].CondoFees' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42', id = 'CondoFees" + idx + "'autocomplete ='off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15 lx-row'> " +
        "      <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left'> " +
        "          <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].ClaimPropertyOnTaxReturn' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack', id = 'ClaimProperty" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val=''/>" +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-10'> " +
        "          Do you claim this property on tax return?" +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divacquiredyearrow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-15 '> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-top-1'> " +
        "              What year did you acquire this property? " +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-row'> " +
        "          <div class='lx-width-550 lx-margin-top-8'> " +
        "              <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].AquiredYear' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack lx-height-42', id = 'AquiredYear" + idx + "', autocomplete = 'off' />" +
        "          </div> " +
        "      </div> " +
        "   </div> " +

        "   <div id = 'divassociationfeerow" + idx + "' class='lx-width-500 lx-margin-top-15'> " +
        "       <div class='lx-square-42 lx-float-left '> " +
        "           <input name='Properties[" + idx + "].FiledExtension' class = 'form-control lx-font-color-lightblack', id = 'FiledExtension" + idx + "' type= 'checkbox' value= 'false' data-val=''/>" +
        "       </div> " +
        "      <div class='lx-float-left lx-font-size-18 lx-margin-left-10 lx-margin-top-10'> " +
        "           Have you filed an extension for your tax returns? " +
        "       </div> " +
        "   </div> " +
        "</div> ";

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: What are your 'five forms' ?

Comment: ... and whats your overall html? It might be very very simple with that

Comment: updated question to show html, this function returns the html as a string as we have .net controls embedded in the forms.

Answer (score 0):

duh I can just wrap the statements in an if(then) which will keep from firing each one all at once example 
if(whichSlide===0){
action1... 
else if(whichSlide===1){
 action2..

almost but I have another problem now, the event handler is firing repeatedly since I used the same handler name and function for all the forms 
I am not sure how to fix that as it came from googles examples.